# remove ember and vi_mode from SpaceShip Theme

Tags: command-line, 22.04, themes

I use Theme Spaceship for my Terminal. But I have two Warnings :
`Warning! The 'ember' section was not found. Removing it from the prompt. Warning! The 'vi_mode' section was not found. Removing it from the prompt.`

And my .zshrc file (I wrote not Comments) :

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="spaceship"
SPACESHIP_PROMPT_ORDER=(user dir host git ruby node line_sep char)
DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"
ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"
HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `vi-mode`:

> Vi-mode is no longer included in Spaceship core and has to be installed separately. A lot of people who don't use vi-mode had problems with that section unexpectedly activating, so we decided that it should be installed manually by those who need it.

[Github](https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-vi-mode) has the source for it. Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-vi-mode.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/spaceship-vi-mode
```

Include spaceship-vi-mode in Oh-My-Zsh plugins list:

```
plugins=($plugins spaceship-vi-mode)
```

`ember` is the same. Source on [github](https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-ember). Installation:

```
https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-ember.git $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/spaceship-ember
```

Include spaceship-ember in Oh-My-Zsh plugins list:

```
plugins=($plugins spaceship-ember)
```